# How was the old GeoCities art made?

Tags: website-design, background, gif, history, art

I've been going through old archives of Geocities pages and I'm slowly becoming obsessed with the general aesthetic. I never had the chance to make my own back in the day as internet was a luxury commodity for my family but I would love to be able to make my own backgrounds and gifs that loosely follow the same strange mix of grainy quality, 2.5D models and cartoony whatevers.

I'm wondering if anyone here had a page going and, if they had any original content on there, remembers which software they used?[image] (Image source https://www.cameronsworld.net/)

Comment: Most of it was "bad" due to software limitations... everything 8 bit, web safe colors, and dithered...

Comment: Back then there was only one setting for gif 128 with dither. I remeber that the Ferrari horse was a part of Corel Photo-Paint "freebies".

Comment: Is this a fake geocities page? I'm not seeing a counter anywhere :)

Comment: This question is too broad as how you create different images seen on that page vary widely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Geocities as such. When people began making websites in the early days of the web, it was a very different environment. There was no high speed broadband, only very slow dial-up modem connections.

Because of that, images file sizes on web pages had to be kept as small as possible so that they would load in a reasonable amount of time.  To do that, image files were compressed using software like Photoshop, to make GIFs with limited colour palettes and dithering, or jpegs with as much compression as you dared.  The result of that is that graphics were not displayed at the quality we now see on the web. They basically looked like crap.

People made artwork then as they do now, using photographs or scans, or they painted/drew it digitally or manipulated it using raster image editing software such as Photoshop, MS Paint, etc.

Comment: Good technical reasons but maybe the main reason is just that Geocities was "for everyone", not just for graphic designers. It is entirely possible to create a good looking page even with limited bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am answering this question too late since it was asked two years ago, but I've experimented a lot with art that “emulates” the look of old internet gifs.

Mainly, I found that the best way to do it is to use image creating/editing websites from that era that are still around (stuff like picmix or glitter text generators for instance), use magic wand selection tools to cut images out of backgrounds instead of tracing them, use “color indexing” with limited color palettes to save your GIFs, and in general keep the images small and sort of rough looking. You can use basically any modern software similar to photoshop to do this, I use GIMP personally since it's free even though the tool set is limited.

If you want to take it even further, you can use editing software of the era, if you want to bother with all the hassle of emulating and what not. My favorite personally is a little program called flying colors, which you can find on the internet archives. I've made quite a few interesting little art pieces in there. Though that program doesn't export directly to GIF, you have to kind of screen record and edit it in a separate program to get the animation (like I said, hassle! But worth it IMO.)

Below is an image I made in a mix of flying colors and GIMP, using a picture of an old fish sticker as inspiration. Happy GIF-ing!

[image: a rainbow fish gif made in flying colors]